# Is there any website that shows steps for different stacks to make a certain app (eCommerce)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stack, mern

Is there any website that shows steps for different stacks to make a certain app (eCommerce)?
For example for making an eCommerce in MERN Stack we have to follow these steps:
A. Front End:

1. Design components
2. Validate user input before sending it to the backend
   B. Backend:
3. Handle the routing
4. Creating MongoDB Models
5. validate user data that send to backend
   x. ...

Answer (score 1):

For example for making an eCommerce in MERN Stack we have to follow these steps:

1. Get design files in Figma/Sketch/PSD slice them into HTML

   - You will need at least those pages designed

     - Main Page
     - Product Collection page/Category page (grid of products with filters)
     - Product Details page
     - Blogpost page
     - Landing page (you going to promote the store so if not linking to a blogpost then you will need a landing page)
2. Choose a headless eCommerce platform that will handle checkout and order processing as well as deliver customer dashboard and all other necessary features, it can be self-hosted or SaaS

   - Self-hosted

     - Magento
     - WooCommerce
     - Sylius
     - Saleor
   - SaaS

     - Shopify
     - BigCommerce
     - Swell
3. Choose engine that you will power your build through, it will be responsible for hosting and compilation of Storefront

   - Gatsby Cloud
   - Netlify
   - Vercel
4. Choose framework to implement the Storefront, React is popular because it's used by major players and ecommerce platforms like Shopify or BigCommerce but Next.js is also good choice.

   - GatsbyJS/React
   - NextJS
5. Explore boilerplates, there are Gatsby connectors to popular platforms like Shopify or WooCommerce, there are middleware like B2storefront that offers cross-platform eCommerce boilerplate.
6. Put HTML markup into the boilerplate and setup build pipeline
7. Connect webhooks
8. Launch

Full disclosure I'm a founder of B2storefront